# Java Regex : How to detect the index of not mached char in a complex regex

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I'm using regex to control an input and I want to get the exact index of the wrong char.

My regex is :

```
^[A-Z]{1,4}(/[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9])?
```

If I type the following input :

```
DATE/201A08
```

Then `macher.group()` (using lookingAt() method) will return "DATE" instead of "DATE/201". Then, I can't know that the wrong index is 9.

Comment: There is no way to know. A close, but not guarantee solution is to make every token optional in the form `A(B(C(D)?)?)?`.

Comment: Thanks for your response but the result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

If I read this right, you can't do this using only one regex.
`^[A-Z]{1,4}(/[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9])?` assumes either a String starting with 1 to 4 characters followed by nothing, or followed by / and exactly 6 digits. So it correctly parses your input as "DATE" as it is valid according to your regex.

Try to split this into two checks. First check if it's a valid DATE
Then, if there's an actual / part, check this against the non-optional pattern.

Comment: But the question is if I have a pattern as this:  '[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]'  and I have the follow input  20Y4.  How can I detect that the wrong index is 3.

Comment: as nhahtdh suggested, have each token be optional and look at the result. `[1-2]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?` should result in 20 for your example so you know that there's a non-digit at position 3.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but in this case the year 999 will be match and it's not what I want. And my big problem is that, I have many different patterns attached to a different inputs. I'm looking for a generic solution if there is one.

Comment: Then try and see if you drop Regex and iterate of the characters and check for things like `Character.isDigit(char ch)` Maybe there's a pure Regex solution but I don't know it and it starts to remind me of the epic "Parse HTML with Regex" Thread.

Comment: It rather reminds of this quote from Jamie Zawinski: _Some people, when confronted with a problem, think ‘I know, I’ll use regular expressions.’ Now they have two problems._

Answer (score 1):

You want to know whether the entire pattern matched, and when not, how far it matched.

There regex fails. A regex test *must* succeed to give results in `group()`. If it also succeeds on a part, one does not know whether all was matched.

The sensible thing to do is split the matching.

```
public class ProgressiveMatch {

    private final String[] regexParts;
    private String group;

    ProgressiveMatch(String... regexParts) {
        this.regexParts = regexParts;
    }

    // lookingAt with (...)?(...=)?...
    public boolean lookingAt(String text) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append('^');
        for (int i = 0; i < regexParts.length; ++i) {
            String part = regexParts[i];
            sb.append("(");
            sb.append(part);
            sb.append(")?");
        }
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(sb.toString());
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(text);
        if (m.lookingAt()) {
            boolean all = true;
            group = "";
            for (int i = 1; i <= regexParts.length; ++i) {
                if (m.group(i) == null) {
                    all = false;
                    break;
                }
                group += m.group(i);
            }
            return all;
        }
        group = null;
        return false;
    }

    // lookingAt with multiple patterns
    public boolean lookingAt(String text) {
        for (int n = regexParts.length; n > 0; --n) {
            // Match for n parts:
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append('^');
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                String part = regexParts[i];
                sb.append(part);
            }
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(sb.toString());
            Matcher m = pattern.matcher(text);
            if (m.lookingAt()) {
                group = m.group();
                return n == regexParts.length;
            }
        }
        group = null;
        return false;
    }

    public String group() {
        return group;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // ^[A-Z]{1,4}(/[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9])?
    ProgressiveMatch match = new ProgressiveMatch("[A-Z]{1,4}", "/",
            "[1-2]", "[0-9]", "[0-9]", "[0-9]", "[0-1]", "[0-9]");
    boolean matched = match.lookingAt("DATE/201A08");
    System.out.println("Matched: " + matched);
    System.out.println("Upto; " + match.group());
}
```

One could make a small DSL in java, like:

```
    ProgressiveMatch match = ProgressiveMatchBuilder
         .range("A", "Z", 1, 4)
         .literal("/")
         .range("1", "2")
         .range("0", "9", 3, 3)
         .range("0", "1")
         .range("0", "9")
         .match();
```